# RegEx capture string which has newline upto first instance of (set of) characters

Tags: regex, vba, xfdf

I am trying to get the first instance of string in following source string

*Input string*

```html
 ><text color="#FFFF00" creationdate="D:20180307100631+04'00'" flags="print,nozoom,norotate" date="D:20180307100652+04'00'" name="a60915a3-1c23-4f6d-b8d4-fbe0dd4890e9" icon="Comment" page="7" rect="351.308000,135.732000,371.308000,153.732000" subject="Sticky Note" title="saddia"
><contents-richtext
><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" xfa:APIVersion="Acrobat:9.0.0" xfa:spec="2.0.2"
><p dir="ltr"
><span dir="ltr" style="font-size:10.0pt;text-align:left;color:#000000;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal"
>As agreed with WPO that any unspecific area use GEN</span
><span dir="ltr" style="font-size:11.0pt;text-align:left;color:#1D477B;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal"
>&#xD;</span
><span dir="ltr" style="font-size:11.0pt;text-align:left;color:#000000;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal"
>&#xD;</span
```

I am trying retrieve output as below

```html
page="7" rect="351.308000,135.732000,371.308000,153.732000" subject="Sticky Note" title="saddia"
><contents-richtext
><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" xfa:APIVersion="Acrobat:9.0.0" xfa:spec="2.0.2"
><p dir="ltr"
><span dir="ltr" style="font-size:10.0pt;text-align:left;color:#000000;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal"
>As agreed with WPO that any unspecific area use GEN</span
```

which is upto first instance of `</span`.

My RegExp is as below which is picking last occurrence of desired end character group:

`page="[0-9]+".+subject="(Text Box|Sticky Note)".+((\s+.+)+);<\/span`

I have limited knowledge of RegEx so please bear with me.

> The snippet is output XFDF (pdf comment export) but it was getting formatted weirdly so I have used html tagging to format.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have corrected it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following regex, the main changes I made were to make the dot lazy, meaning that it stops at the *first* pattern after the dot.  This is to prevent the pattern from combing only once over the entire text.

```
page="[0-9]+".+?subject="(?:Text Box|Sticky Note)".+?<\/span
```

### Demo

Note *carefully* that in order for the above pattern to work, the regex must be done in DOT ALL mode, meaning that dot also matches across newlines.

In VBA, which doesn't have a formal DOT ALL mode, we can simulate it using `[\s\S]`:

```
page="[0-9]+"[\s\S]+?subject="(?:Text Box|Sticky Note)"[\s\S]+?<\/span
```

Comment: How to set this mode in VBA while testing?

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij Use a character class `[\s\S]` to match any character.  I'm not an expert with VBA, but the above pattern should work.  Let me update my answer.

Comment: That nailed it. Thank you very much for your answer!